# Why I m still getting data from my webflux spring boot even if I unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, spring-webflux, project-reactor, angular2-observables, unsubscribe

I'm learning about the reactive web, for a tutorial I wanted to get some twitter hashtag result search from my spring webflux rest service to an angular 6 client.

When hitting my `localhost:8081/search/test` in chrome, I m getting the tweets in a json format in a reactive way (tweet by tweet and browser is showing every coming one).

so for more pleasure, I made a small angular search input and I would show in console tweets

the issue is when I search for `java` tag I will get console logs then if I try to search for `spring` tag I will have spring tweets logged in the console and the java ones are still coming

I did some research and I found that I should unsubscribe my consumer from the flux.

I tried to implement this but no success

Here is What I tried

**Spring WebFlux Controller**

```
private TwitHashLocalService localService;
    private TwitHashRemoteService remoteService;

    @GetMapping(value="search/{tag}",produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE) 
    public Flux<Tweet> getByTag(@PathVariable String tag) throws TwitterException{
        return localService.findByTag(tag).mergeWith(remoteService.findByTag(tag).doOnNext(tweet -> localService.save(tweet)));
    }
```

**My services**

*local mongo db*

```
private MongoService mongoService;

    public Flux<Tweet> findByTag(String tag) {

        return mongoService.findByTag(tag);
    }
```

*remote twitter stream flux*

```
public Flux<Tweet> findByTag(String hashtag) throws TwitterException {

    return Flux.create(sink -> {
        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(configuration).getInstance();
        twitterStream.onStatus(status -> sink.next(Tweet.fromStatus(status,hashtag)));
        twitterStream.onException(sink::error);
        twitterStream.filter(hashtag);
        sink.onCancel(twitterStream::shutdown);
    }); 

}
```

**ANGULAR**

**My reactive twitter search service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ITweet } from './itweet';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReactiveTwitterService {

    myTweets: ITweet[] = new Array();

    tweetTag: string;

    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/search';

    constructor(private http_client: HttpClient) { }

    getTweetStream(tag): Observable<Array<ITweet>> {

        this.myTweets = [];
        const url = this.baseUrl + '/' + tag;

        return Observable.create(observer => {
            const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
            eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
                console.log('received event');
                const json = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(json);
                console.log(json.tweetData.name, json.tweetData.text, json.tag);
                this.myTweets.push(new ITweet(json.tweetData.name, json.tweetData.text, json.tag));
                observer.next(this.myTweets);
            };
            eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
                // readyState === 0 (closed) means the remote source closed the connection,
                // so we can safely treat it as a normal situation. Another way of detecting the end of the stream
                // is to insert a special element in the stream of events, which the client can identify as the last one.
                if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
                    console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
                    eventSource.close();
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                    observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
                }
            };
        });   
    }   
}
```

**component search bar**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveTwitterService } from '../reactive-twitter.service';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ITweet } from '../itweet';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-serach-bar',
    templateUrl: './serach-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./serach-bar.component.css']
})
export class SerachBarComponent implements OnInit {
    innerWidth: number;


    subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    placeholder = 'search';

    styleClass = {
        wide_screen: 'w3-input w3-light-grey',
        break_point: 'w3-input w3-white'
    };

    tweets: Observable<ITweet[]>;

    constructor(private twiterService: ReactiveTwitterService) { }

    doSearch(tag) {
        console.log('test' + tag);
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.tweets = this.twiterService.getTweetStream(tag);
        this.subscription.add(this.tweets.subscribe());
    }


    ngOnInit() {
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    }

    getStyle() {
        return (innerWidth > 769) ? this.styleClass.wide_screen : this.styleClass.break_point;
    }
}
```

*As you see in the search I m trying to unsubscribe before researching but this is not working*

**What should I do?**

Comment: I just tried to close the  eventSource if it was created but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1) Make sure the cancelation is propagated in RxJs

From the code I see, there is no cancelation handler on the Angular side.

Try to do the following, to react on unsubscribe at JS side:

```
Observable.create(observer => {
        const eventSource = new EventSource(url);

        // your code here 

        return () => eventSource.close(); // on cancel function
    });
```

## 2) Add `.log()`ing

I would recommend adding additional logging to the Reactor's pipe, so it will be clear what signals are propagated through the pipe. Use `.log()` operator for that purpose.

## 3) Make sure the EventSource is really closed on the browser side.

Use your browsers debug console to observe all opened connections to the server. Make sure, that after changing tag/ cleaning search request the connection is closed

## 4) Remember about eventual consistency

All propagated events through the reactive pipe are an async and non-blocking, so there could be some delay between actual action and final cancelation on the server side

Comment: thank you, I want to say that using your advice and I also changed in unsubscribe by unsubscribing then reinstanciating a new subscription wrapper for the next search value

Comment: Glad to help you)

Comment: one last question do you have any book recomendation so I can master reactive in a production environement

Comment: :D You may look at mine one XD -> https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/hands-reactive-programming-spring-5. It is not fully related to production, but definitely, you may learn something from it :D. Another good book is -> https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-design-patterns

Comment: I m happy that I got helped by a writter :) may god bless you